# Using the Windows SetTimer() function

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am getting confused with the SetTimer() function.

SetTimer() takes three parameters:

```
SetTimer(1,2000,Timerflow);
```

However I've seen another version of SetTimer that takes four parameters:

```
SetTimer(NULL,1,2000,Timerflow);
```

What is the difference between these two functions?

I know SetTimer() Three parameters. But when I try the four parameter SetTimer() function, I get the error:

```
error C2660: 'SetTimer' : function does not take 4 parameters
```

So what is the main difference and what causes this error?

Answer (score 8):

The 4-parameter version is the plain Win32 API version, and the first parameter is a window handle.

The 3-parameter version is a member of MFC's CWnd class, and works with the window handle of the CWnd instance for which you call it.

If you need to call the 4-parameter Win32 API from within a method of a CWnd-derived object, do this:

```
::SetTimer(NULL, 1, 2000, Timerflow);
```

Answer (score 4):

The only Windows API called SetTimer takes four parameters. Presumably the other one is part of MFC or some other framework, and the first parameter is implied by the object you call it on. For example:

```
CWnd * w = .... // get window somehow
w->SetTimer(1,2000,Timerflow);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use SetTimer to create a timer in GUI classes such as the MFC's CWnd, you can use the 3-parameter form:

```
UINT  SetTimer( 
  UINT  nIDEvent,             //  timer  identifier 
  UINT  uElapse,              //  time-out  value 
  TIMERPROC  lpTimerFunc      //  address  of  timer  procedure
);
```

But if you use it in non-GUI classes, you have to use the 4-parameter form. The first parameter is to specify which GUI component will respond for the timer event. This version of the function is called from Win32 API.

```
UINT  SetTimer( 
  HWND  hWnd,                //  handle  of  window  for  timer  messages 
  UINT  nIDEvent,            //  timer  identifier 
  UINT  uElapse,             //  time-out  value 
  TIMERPROC  lpTimerFunc     //  address  of  timer  procedure 
);
```

It is very simple, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx, the first and last parameters are optional. Therefore, you can have a SetTimer call with even 2 parameters (not recommended however). The error is most likely from an incorrect cast (needs a uint_ptr, you give an hwnd, for example)